# Formatting Phone Number via a webservice

Tags: angular

In my webpage, I would like to format the phone number. For example `67291961` by `067/29.19.61`

In my page `dashboad-homepage.component.html`:

I have the variable `welcomeMessage` which allows to display the message below: (Here is a screenshot)

```
{{welcomeMessage}} <a href="mailto:{{agent.MAIL}}">{{agent.MAIL}}</a>
```

[image]

To be able to format my phone number, I have to go on the page `dashboad-homepage.component.ts`and then format the variable `agentPhone` but how to format `agentPhone` ?

I know that the problem is below, but I don't know how to format it ?

```
prepareDataForTemplate(res){
if(res.RETURNCODE == 'OKK00'){
this.mifid = res.HOME.MIFID;
this.news = [];
this.securities = [];
this.agent = res.HOME.AGENT;
this.message = res.HOME.MESSAGE;
this.welcomeMessage = res.HOME.WELCOME;
this.i18n.agentName = this.agent.NAME;
this.i18n.agentMail = this.agent.MAIL;
this.i18n.agentPhone = this.agent.PHONE;
this.nOSTs = res.HOME.OSTNUMERO;
for(var i = 0; i < res.HOME.ARTICLE.length; i++){
var myvar = {
objet: res.HOME.ARTICLE[i].OBJET,
cours: res.HOME.ARTICLE[i].COURS,
source: res.HOME.ARTICLE[i].SOURCE,
id: res.HOME.ARTICLE[i].NUMERO,
date: res.HOME.ARTICLE[i].DATE[8]+res.HOME.ARTICLE[i].DATE[9]+"/"+res.HOME.ARTICLE[i].DATE[5]+res.HOME.ARTICLE[i].DATE[6],
dateH: this.helpers.formatDateHeureAS400HeureHP(res.HOME.ARTICLE[i].HEURINTRO),
svm: res.HOME.ARTICLE[i].SVM,
ticker: res.HOME.ARTICLE[i].STOCK,
DATEINTRO: this.helpers.formatDateHeureAS400DayMonth(res.HOME.ARTICLE[i].DATEINTRO, res.HOME.ARTICLE[i].HEURINTRO),
HEURINTRO: this.helpers.formatDateHeureAS400HoursMinutes(res.HOME.ARTICLE[i].DATEINTRO, res.HOME.ARTICLE[i].HEURINTRO)
};
```

For information, here is an idea of the code `dashboad-homepage.component.ts`, sorry there are many lines:

```
import { Component, OnInit, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { MySharedService } from "src/app/shared/services/my-shared.service";
import { DataLayerService } from "src/app/shared/services/data-layer.service";
import { LocalStoreService } from "src/app/shared/services/local-store.service";
import { HelpersService } from "src/app/shared/services/helpers.service";
import { echartStyles } from 'src/app/shared/echart-styles';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { DateddmmyyyyhiPipe } from 'src/app/shared/pipes/dateddmmyyyyhi.pipe';
import { TimehhmmPipe } from 'src/app/shared/pipes/timehhmm.pipe';
import * as am4core from "@amcharts/amcharts4/core";
import * as am4charts from "@amcharts/amcharts4/charts";
import am4themes_animated from "@amcharts/amcharts4/themes/animated";

am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);



@Component({
selector: 'app-dashboad-home',
templateUrl: './dashboad-home.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./dashboad-home.component.css'],
providers: [ DateddmmyyyyhiPipe, TimehhmmPipe]
})
export class DashboadHomeComponent implements OnInit {

currentPortfolio: any;
sectionTitle: String;
pageTitle: String;
agent;
news: any;
markets: any;
securities: any = [];
variationPlace: any;
svmToTickers: any;

showCharts: false;
placeNames: any;

chartLineOption3: any;
lineChartReturn: any;

message;
welcomeMessage;
nOSTs;
nCGIs;
header_info;
mifid;
showHistoryCharts;
singleHistoryCharts;

i18n;
subscribedTo;

constructor(
private shrd: MySharedService,
private api: DataLayerService,
private helpers: HelpersService,
private LS: LocalStoreService,
private zone: NgZone,
private router: Router,
private dateddmmyyyyhi: DateddmmyyyyhiPipe,
private timehhmm: TimehhmmPipe,

) {

this.agent = {};
this.agent.MAIL = '';
this.i18n = {
lastErrorDate: '',
lastErrorHeure: '',
lastConnexionDate: '',
lastConnexionHeure: '',
agentName: '',
agentPhone: '',
agentMail: ''
}
this.message = 0;
this.mifid = {};
this.markets = {};
this.header_info = {};
this.showHistoryCharts = [];
this.singleHistoryCharts = [];
this.subscribedTo = [];
this.nOSTs = [];
this.nCGIs = [];
this.variationPlace = [];
this.placeNames = [
{
exist: false,
name: '',
id: 0
},
{
exist: false,
name: '',
id: 0
},
{
exist: false,
name: '',
id: 0
},
];
}


private chart: am4charts.XYChart;


// AM Chart,
ngAfterViewInit() {
this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {

});
}

ngOnDestroy() {
this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
if (this.chart) {
this.chart.dispose();
}
});
}
// Amchart

ngOnInit() {

this.currentPortfolio = this.shrd.getData('currentPortfolio');
this.sectionTitle = "My Title";
this.pageTitle = "Welcome";
this.svmToTickers = {};

this.header_info = this.LS.getItem("LX_INFO_HEADER");
this.i18n.lastConnexionHeure = this.timehhmm.transform(this.header_info.LAHECO);
this.i18n.lastConnexionDate = this.dateddmmyyyyhi.transform(this.header_info.LADACO);
this.i18n.lastErrorHeure = this.timehhmm.transform(this.header_info.LAHEPWD);
this.i18n.lastErrorDate = this.dateddmmyyyyhi.transform(this.header_info.LADAPWD);

this.lineChartReturn = {
...{}, ...{
tooltip: {
trigger: 'axis',
position: function (pt) {
return [pt[0], '10%'];
}
},
xAxis: {
type: 'category',
// boundaryGap: false,
//show: true,
data: []
},
yAxis: {
type: 'value',
show: true
},
series: [
{
name:'',
type:'line',
smooth:true,
symbol: 'none',
sampling: 'average',
itemStyle: {
color: 'rgba(255, 152, 0, .6)',// 'rgb(255, 70, 131)'
},
areaStyle: {
color: 'rgba(255, 152, 0, 0.15)',
origin: 'start'
},
lineStyle: {
// width: 1,
color: 'rgba(255, 152, 0, .6)',
},
data: []
}
]
}
};

this.chartLineOption3 = {
...echartStyles.lineNoAxis, ...{
series: [{
data: [],
lineStyle: {
color: 'rgba(102, 51, 153, .86)',
width: 3,
shadowColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, .2)',
shadowOffsetX: -1,
shadowOffsetY: 8,
shadowBlur: 10
},
label: { show: false, color: '#212121' },
type: 'line',
smooth: true,
itemStyle: {
borderColor: 'rgba(69, 86, 172, 0.86)'
}
}]
}
};

this.initiate();
}

designAmcharts(divID, instrumentTitle, amChartsData){
// Themes begin
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
// Themes end

// Create chart instance
var chart = am4core.create(divID, am4charts.XYChart);

chart.dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:MM ";
chart.numberFormatter.numberFormat = "#.#a €";
chart.numberFormatter.bigNumberPrefixes = [
{ "number": 1e+3, "suffix": "K" },
{ "number": 1e+6, "suffix": "M" },
{ "number": 1e+9, "suffix": "B" }
];

// Chart title
var title = chart.titles.create();
title.text = instrumentTitle;
title.fontSize = 20;
title.paddingBottom = 10;

// Add data
chart.data = amChartsData;
/*
chart.data = [{ "date": new Date(2020, 6, 1), "observed": 720000, "easing": 720000, "projection": 720000,"stricter": 720000
}, {
......
}
];
*/

// Create axes
var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
dateAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
dateAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 30;
dateAxis.renderer.labels.template.rotation = -45;
dateAxis.renderer.labels.template.horizontalCenter = "right";
dateAxis.renderer.labels.template.verticalCenter = "middle";

var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

valueAxis.renderer.labels.template.verticalCenter = "bottom";
valueAxis.renderer.labels.template.dx = -5;
valueAxis.renderer.labels.template.dy = 10;
valueAxis.renderer.maxLabelPosition = 0.95;

valueAxis.title.marginRight = 5;

// Create series
function createSeries(field, name, color, dashed) {
var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
series.dataFields.valueY = field;
series.dataFields.dateX = "date";
series.name = name;
series.tooltipText = "[bold]{name}[/]\n{dateX}: [b]{valueY}[/]";
series.strokeWidth = 2;
//series.smoothing = "monotoneX";
series.stroke = color;

if (dashed) {
series.strokeDasharray = "5 3";
}
return series;
}
createSeries("price", "price", am4core.color("#A60027"), false);

chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
/**/
}

getSubcriptionsList() {
this.api.getMarketsDataSubcriptionsList(this.currentPortfolio)
.subscribe((response: {}) => {
this.getUnansweredCGI();
// Save in the
this.prepareDataForMarketDataSubscriptions(response);
});
}

relaunch(){
this.initiate();
}

getUnansweredCGI() {
this.api.getUnansweredCGI(this.currentPortfolio, "O", 0)
.subscribe((response: {}) => {
this.getHomePageContent();
this.prepareDataForUnansweredCGI(response);
});
}
prepareDataForUnansweredCGI(res){
if(res.RETURNCODE == 'OKK00'){
this.nCGIs = res.CGI;
this.LS.setItem("LX_num_CGIs", res.CGI.length);
}else {
// Service to report and manage errors (faire remonter au Backend)
}
}
getHistoryDataFormated2(data, dates){
let toReturn = this.lineChartReturn;
toReturn.xAxis.data = dates;
toReturn.series[0].data = data;

return toReturn;
}
getHistoryDataFormated(data){
let toReturn = this.chartLineOption3;
toReturn.series[0].data = data;
return toReturn;
}

getHomePageContent() {
this.api.getHomePageContent(this.currentPortfolio)
.subscribe((response: {}) => {
this.prepareDataForTemplate(response);
});
}


initiate(){
this.getAllMarkets();

}

getH(i, svm){
this.api.getInstrumentHistoryEquities(svm, '1D')
.subscribe((response: {}) => {
this.prepareDataForHistory(response, i);
});
}

getHIndices(i, svm){
this.api.getInstrumentHistoryIndices(svm, '1D')
.subscribe((response: {}) => {
this.prepareDataForHistory(response, i);
});
}

prepareDataForHistory(res, internalID){
for(var i = 0; i < this.securities.length; i++){
if(this.securities[i].internalID == internalID && res.HISTO.POINT.length > 0){
for(var j = 0; j < res.HISTO.POINT.length; j++){
this.securities[i].amChartsData.push({
"date": new Date(res.HISTO.POINT[j].DATE+" "+res.HISTO.POINT[j].TIME),
"price": res.HISTO.POINT[j].PRICE
});
}
this.securities[i].historyExist = true;
}
}
for(var i = 0; i < this.securities.length; i++){
if(this.securities[i].internalID == internalID && this.singleHistoryCharts.indexOf(internalID) == -1){
if(this.securities[i].amChartsData.length > 0){
this.designAmcharts(("chartdiveq"+i), this.securities[i].name, this.securities[i].amChartsData);
this.singleHistoryCharts.push(internalID);
this.showHistoryCharts.push(i);
console.log(this.showHistoryCharts)
}
}
}
}

canShowHistoryCharts(i){
return this.showHistoryCharts.indexOf(i) > -1;
}

prepareDataForMarketDataSubscriptions(res){
if(res.RETURNCODE == 'OKK00'){
console.log(res)
for(var i = 0; i < res['ABO'].length; i++){
if(res['ABO'][i]['ABOCLIENT'] == 'Y'){
this.subscribedTo.push(res['ABO'][i]['PLAC']);
}
}
this.LS.setItem("LX_MARKET_DATA", this.subscribedTo);
}else {

}
}
prepareDataForTemplate(res){
if(res.RETURNCODE == 'OKK00'){
this.mifid = res.HOME.MIFID;
this.news = [];
this.securities = [];
this.agent = res.HOME.AGENT;
this.message = res.HOME.MESSAGE;
this.welcomeMessage = res.HOME.WELCOME;
this.i18n.agentName = this.agent.NAME;
this.i18n.agentMail = this.agent.MAIL;
this.i18n.agentPhone = this.agent.PHONE;
this.nOSTs = res.HOME.OSTNUMERO;
for(var i = 0; i < res.HOME.ARTICLE.length; i++){
var myvar = {
objet: res.HOME.ARTICLE[i].OBJET,
cours: res.HOME.ARTICLE[i].COURS,
source: res.HOME.ARTICLE[i].SOURCE,
id: res.HOME.ARTICLE[i].NUMERO,
date: res.HOME.ARTICLE[i].DATE[8]+res.HOME.ARTICLE[i].DATE[9]+"/"+res.HOME.ARTICLE[i].DATE[5]+res.HOME.ARTICLE[i].DATE[6],
dateH: this.helpers.formatDateHeureAS400HeureHP(res.HOME.ARTICLE[i].HEURINTRO),
svm: res.HOME.ARTICLE[i].SVM,
ticker: res.HOME.ARTICLE[i].STOCK,
DATEINTRO: this.helpers.formatDateHeureAS400DayMonth(res.HOME.ARTICLE[i].DATEINTRO, res.HOME.ARTICLE[i].HEURINTRO),
HEURINTRO: this.helpers.formatDateHeureAS400HoursMinutes(res.HOME.ARTICLE[i].DATEINTRO, res.HOME.ARTICLE[i].HEURINTRO)
};
this.news.push(myvar);
}
for(var i = 0; i < res.HOME.PREFERENCE.VALEUR.length; i++){
let curSec= res.HOME.PREFERENCE.VALEUR[i];
let timsec = i*10*45;
if( (curSec.SVM > 0 && curSec.TYP == 'A') || (curSec.TYP == 'I' && curSec.COD.length > 0) ){
this.securities.push({
type: curSec.TYP,
name: curSec.LIB,
svm: curSec.SVM,
code: curSec.COD,
internalID: curSec.SVM+'-'+curSec.COD,
last: curSec.COURS.VALUE,
variation: ((curSec.COURS.VALUE/curSec.COURS.CLOTURE-1)*100),
historyExist: false,
historyDataDates: [],
historyData: [],
history: {},
history2: {},
showLine: true,
amChartsData: []
});
// if(!this.alreadyAskedHistoryFor(curSec)){
setTimeout(() => {
if(curSec.TYP == 'A' && curSec.SVM > 0){
this.getH(curSec.SVM+'-'+curSec.COD, curSec.SVM);
// this.singleHistoryCharts.push(curSec.SVM);
}else if(curSec.TYP == 'I' && curSec.COD.length > 0){
this.getHIndices(curSec.SVM+'-'+curSec.COD, curSec.COD);
// this.singleHistoryCharts.push(curSec.COD);
}
}, timsec);
// }
} else {
this.securities.push({historyExist: false, showLine: false});
}
}


this.variationPlace = [res.HOME.VARIATIONPLACE1, res.HOME.VARIATIONPLACE2, res.HOME.VARIATIONPLACE3];
this.updatePlaceNames(res.HOME.PREFERENCE.PLAC1, res.HOME.PREFERENCE.PLAC2, res.HOME.PREFERENCE.PLAC3);


// Variation places
// Get the last history

}else {
// Service to report and manage errors (faire remonter au Backend)
}
}

alreadyAskedHistoryFor(curSec){
let res = false;
if(curSec.TYP == 'A' && curSec.SVM > 0){
res = this.singleHistoryCharts.indexOf(curSec.SVM) > -1;
}else if(curSec.TYP == 'I' && curSec.COD.length > 0){
res = this.singleHistoryCharts.indexOf(curSec.COD) > -1;
}
return res;
}


updatePlaceNames(pl1, pl2, pl3){
// console.log(pl1, pl2, pl3);
this.placeNames = [{
exist: (pl1 >= 1 ? true : false ),
name: this.markets[pl1],
id: pl1
}, {
exist: (pl2 >= 1 ? true : false ),
name: this.markets[pl2],
id: pl2
}, {
exist: (pl3 >= 1 ? true : false ),
name: this.markets[pl3],
id: pl3
}];
// console.log(this.placeNames, this.variationPlace);

}

getAllMarkets(){
this.api.getParametersAllMarkets()
.subscribe((response) => {
this.getSubcriptionsList();
if(response['RETURNCODE'] == 'OKK00'){
for(var i = 0; i < response['TEXTE']['LISTE'].length; i++){
this.markets[parseInt(response['TEXTE']['LISTE'][i].CODE)] = response['TEXTE']['LISTE'][i].COURT;
}
}else {
// manage this error
}
});
}

getAndCacheSignaletique(svm){
this.getTicker(svm);
}

getTicker(svm){
this.api.getInstrumentInfo(svm)
.subscribe((response) => {
if(response['RETURNCODE'] == 'OKK00'){
this.svmToTickers[svm] = response['ADVTITRE'].BASIQUETITRE.STOCK;
// console.log(this.svmToTickers);
/*
TODO this.cacheSignaletique(response);
*/
}else {
// manage this error
}
});
}

getTickerFromSVM(svm){
// TODO Check if it's cached.
// console.log(this.svmToTickers);
return this.svmToTickers[svm] ? this.svmToTickers[svm] : "";
}

goToDetails(n){
let detailsId = n.type == 'I' ? n.code : n.svm
// TODO if it's index go to Indices
// this.router.navigateByUrl("/markets/details/"+detailsId);
this.goToDeatilsSVM(detailsId);
}

goToDetailsFromPerf(l){
this.goToDeatilsSVM(l.SVM);
}

goToDeatilsSVM(svm){
this.router.navigateByUrl("/markets/details/"+svm);
}

goToOSTNews(l){
// console.log(l)
this.router.navigateByUrl("/markets/details/"+l.svm+"/news/"+l.id);
}

goToMails(){
this.router.navigateByUrl("/dashboard/mails");
}

goToOSTs(){
this.router.navigateByUrl("/portfolio/corporateActions");
}

goToCGIs(){
this.router.navigateByUrl("/portfolio/recommandations");
}


showInformationsOnPTF(){
return (this.nOSTs.length > 0 || this.nCGIs.length > 0 ); // OR another thing messages length
}

showLastLogin(){
return this.header_info.LADACO > 0;
}

showLastError(){
return this.header_info.LADAPWD > 0;
}
}
```

If you have an idea, I'm interested.

Comment: DO you have fixed number length for the phone numbers? Do they vary in formatting ex: 66678789 - 066/67.87.89 0r 666698900 - 0666/69.89.00?

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara: There is no fixed length and the formatting can vary, but I recommend this type of formatting -> `0666/69.89.00`, i dont' see how to do this?

Comment: Is there any range for the numbers length like 8 - 10 or 8-12 and do you have any specific formats for that?

Comment: @Apoorva Chikara: Ehh no there is no specific format. The desired range is `8-12`

Comment: Please indent your code, if not already just for your own sake, for anyone you expect to read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the regex to do this, it is a simple solution using regex:

```js
const phone = '9876543210'; //change it's value 
let result = '';

switch(phone.length) {

    case 8: 
             result=  phone.replace(/(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})/, "0$1/$2.$3.$4");  
               break;
    case 9:  
            result = phone.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})/, "0$1/$2.$3.$4");
             break;
     case 10:  
            result = phone.replace(/(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})/, "0$1/$2.$3.$4.$5");
             break;  
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks, you think that I can adapt this on my code?

Comment: As of now, you can it seems the phone length is variable and if the phone length doesn't vary, you can use it.